# Connect with VSCode PowerShell to Docker SQL Server SMO PS Provider?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, docker, visual-studio-code, smo

Docker SQL Server 2019 Ubuntu

This works and opens a console:
Connect with SSMS to localhost,1433
Rightclick a database > contextmenu > Start PowerShell > console opens with path: PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost,1433\DEFAULT+sa\Databases<myDatabase>>

But when I try to open VSCode with 'Code .' it opens VSCode with path c:\Windows\System32

Trying the same path in VSCode PowerShell doesnt work:
VSCode PowerShell > import-module sqlserver > sqlserver: > cd \SQL\localhost,1433\DEFAULT+sa\Databases<myDatabase>\

I get the error: SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to 'localhost,1433\DEFAULT+sa'. [SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to 'localhost,1433\DEFAULT+sa'.]

The furthest I can go is: cd "SQL\localhost,1433" which results in: PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost,1433>
When I do 'dir' I get this message: WARNING: The provider was unable to determine the instances runnning on localhost,1433. You can still try to connect by providing the instance name.
When I try: cd "DEFAULT+sa" I get the error: Set-Location: Cannot find path 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost,1433\DEFAULT+sa' because it does not exist.

I'm stuck at this step

Comment: In your `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1` file do you have `Import-Module SqlServer`? That would allow you to at least `cd "...the...database...path..."` from a PowerShell prompt, including the one inside VS Code. Also, it only works that way with Windows Authentication (not SQL Login Authentication).

Comment: That's probably the explanation, I connect with SSMS using SQL login and that somehow transfers the connection to the PowerShell console when I do 'contextmenu > Start PowerShell'. But in VSCode PowerShell SMO I haven't done that and that's why it doesnt work